# Salvar dados de uma array em um banco de dados

Tags: c#, json, array

Preciso gravar o conteúdo de uma array que retornou de uma deserilização Json (retorno de um Json com mais de um nível), segue a linha com o método que extrai o array:

```
        Departmants dept = new Departmants();
        dept.Property1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Department[]>(json);
```

Classe com a estrutura da array:

```
   public class Departmants
    {
        public Department[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool temSub{ get; set; }
        public Sub[] subitem{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool temSub{ get; set; }
        public object[] subitem{ get; set; }
    }
```

Agradeço desde já a quem puder auxiliar.

Comment: Qual abordagem está usando? EntityFramework?

Comment: Rodrigo, estou utilizando o Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: A pergunta do Rodrigo é se você está usando algum ORM, tipo EntityFramework, Dapper ou se está usando ADO.NET no seu projeto.

Comment: só um detalhe, Departments e não Departmants ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem algumas opções, usar **EntityFramework**, **Dapper**, **ADO.Net** ou qualquer outro.
Vou colocar aqui dois exemplos de insert utilizando o seu objeto.
Agora é só adaptar para as suas colunas e modelo da tabela e realizar o **Insert**, **Update** ou **Delete**. Eu particularmente gosto de trabalhar com o **Dapper**.

**Com ADO:**

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql =  "INSERT INTO Departmants (coluna1 ,coluna1) VALUES(@param1, @param2)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = Departmants.name;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Bool).value = Departmants.temsub;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Com Dapper:**
Adicione o pacote no Nuget no **Package Manager Console**

> Install-Package Dapper

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    const string sql = @"INSERT INTO Departmants (coluna1 ,coluna1) VALUES(@param1, @param2)";

    db.Execute(sql, new { param1 = Departmants.name, param2 = Departmants.temsub }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!